# Create new directory in tmp folder and store uploaded file

Tags: php, file-upload, directory, temporary-files, tmp

I want to store a file uploaded by the user in my Temp folder (C:\Temp) using php but not sure how to go about it.

Comment: It might be better to put all uploads in just the temp dir. If you keep them together in one temp dir or many sub dirs, you should ALWAYS rename what they are uploading. Using their session ID + salt is a safe way to not have naming conflicts. This removes a way for hackers to upload a script they can execute via some exploit in another service. You don't want them to know the path and name of the script they just uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a lot going on there and probably not a good use of `tempnam`.  If you would echo the variables/paths that you are creating it would be much clearer.

If your webserver has permission to create directories in `C:/Temp` and you're OK using the `time` or `microtime` then just this:

```
$fileName = basename($_FILES["fileName"]["name"]);
$tmpName = $_FILES["fileName"]["tmp_name"];

$newDir = "C:/Temp/FileDrop" . microtime(true);
mkdir($newDir);
move_uploaded_file($tmpName, "$newDir/$fileName");
```

You could also generate a unique ID:

```
$newDir = "C:/Temp/" . uniqid("FileDrop");
```

I used `C:/Temp` because you mentioned that but don't show what `sys_get_temp_dir` returns or if you want to use that.

Comment: Well, the webserver probably doesn't have permission to `C\Temp` so check that.  The `mkdir` should fail as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the wrong directory with `mkdir()`, you need to create the folder in `/Temp`. You also shouldn't call `tempnam()` a second time, it will create a different temp file.

Instead of first creating a file in `sys_get_temp_dir()`, create it in your `/Temp` directory.

```
                $tempDir = tempnam("C:/Temp", 'FileDrop');
                unlink($tempDir);
                mkdir($tempDir);
                move_uploaded_file($tmpName, "$tempDir/$fileName");
```

Comment: Try adding `C:` prefix when calling `tempnam`

Comment: It seems that you are using windows, please try `"c:\temp\". $filename` (make sure c:\temp exists and is writable)

Comment: @KenLee Windows allows both forward and backslash in pathnames.